# Jenkins: Sending email based on each build step result in same Jenkins Job

Tags: email, jenkins

I am just wondering how to send out email with [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) based on each build step result on same Jenkins Job. Here is my scenario

My Jenkins job has 3 Build steps

Build Step1:

```
   Pull latest code from github and Build the app - Gradle task which build the Jar
```

Build Step2:

```
   Run all Tests against that Jar - Gradle Task which runs all Junit tests and provide Report files.
```

Post Build Action:

```
   If Build step1 fails -> Send email telling Build fails and Console Log with Exception detials

   If Build success and Tests run -> Send email with Test Reports
```

I think i would need to write Pre-send script for Email-Ext plugin. But i am not sure how to write this script. Please assist.

Answer (score 10):

In a normal configuration, if Build Step 1 fails, Build Step 2 will not execute anyways.

And if Build Step 2 (Test) fail, the build will be marked "Unstable", not "Failed".

**Email-ext** already supports triggers for these.

- Scroll to your **Editable Email Notification** section.
- Click **<kbd>Advanced Settings...</kbd>** button.
- Look under **Triggers** section.
- Click **<kbd>Add Trigger</kbd>** button.

You want to configure a trigger for "**Failure**" and a trigger for "**Unstable**" (you will also probably want a trigger for "**Success**")

In your "Failure" trigger, write the email content you want for when the build fails (Build Step 1 failure will cause this for you).
In your "Unstable" trigger, write the email content you want for when the test cases fail.
In your "Success" trigger, write the email content you want for when everything was successful and you want to send the test report.

**Alternative:**
Or you can look into [**Any Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin) plugin (which should allow post-build actions, like email-ext, to be executed as a build step), and **[Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)** plugin (which allows to create conditions for each build step). Combine the two and create conditions when you want to trigger the email-ext build step. However I have not tried this and can't guarantee this will work.

Comment: Thanks Slav. I tried Option 1, But doesn't seem to be working as expected. In case of "Unstable"(Where build step1 pass and Step2 fail), still seeing it as "Failure" instead of "Unstable". Am i missing something?

Comment: How are you launching the tests? If you are doing it from command line, it isn't treated as "tests", but rather a "build". Try this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin

Comment: The combination of Any Build Step and email-ext is tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customizing email ext consider breaking up job into 2 jobs:

- job 1 builds and has this post build configuration

  - *Build Other Projects* with *Trigger only if build succeeds* checked
  - Configure email-ext to only send mail in case of failure
- job 2 runs test and sends mail

For both jobs set job parameters in (job)/Configure/Advanced Project Options to

- *Use custom workspace* to share the same workspace
- *Block build when up/downstream project is building* to avoid overwriting

If you'd also like to attach test results to job 1 in case it was successful, add in post build steps in job 1 *Aggregate downstream test results*.

Comment: @Tang, Thanks for answering this. Splitting into 2 jobs, I already did that which is working fine. For this simple tasks, i don't want to have 2 jobs which is cumbersome to maintain. So i wanted this in single job.