# Jenkins - Build Steps

Tags: jenkins

I am currently writing a Jenkins job to connect to different sql servers to check if all the application servers are up and running.

What I want to achieve:

1. Connect to QA SQL Server, run the query to verify server status.
   Parse the Jenkins log and If any of the servers is down, send a mail to `destination1@abc.com` with the server name and server id.
2. Connect to Parallel SQL Server, run the query to verify server status.
   Parse the Jenkins log and If any of the servers is down, send a mail to `destination2@abc.com` with the server name and server id.

Challenge I am facing:

I have used 2 build steps (Windows batch command) i.e. one for parallel and one for QA. But, if the first one fails, Jenkins doesn't execute the second one.

Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: Why not make them 2 separate jobs?

Comment: hello, don't want to create multiple jobs for this small task and we already have several jobs configured for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution would be to write the second build step as a Post-Build step, using the [JENKINS Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)

That post build step would be executed even if the first build step fails.

But the more modern and logical solution would be to execute them in their own job, using the [JENKINS Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), or even [Jenkins pipelines, as shown in "Jobs in parallel"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel).

Comment: How do i achieve the mailing part i.e. different mails for different build steps?
The Post build task is common to all the build steps right.

Comment: @shiva That is why I suggest having two separate jobs: each one can have its own associated mailing list. Since you don't want separate jobs, try and look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/24083316/6309.

Comment: Thanks @Vonc. I settled to use same mail for both the lower environments.

Comment: I have more question. How do i highlight one line of the console log output.

Example:

Below Servers are down in UAT -->( I want to Bold and increase the font for this line)
Server1
Server2
Server3

Comment: @shiva Not sure: that would be a good new question of its own.